# Easy Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Have an excel question.  I am looking to see if something states "complete" in one cell and if yes then look at a date in another cell and then count how many are within 30 day period of today's date. Below I know its wrong but might be able to get a better idea of what I am trying to do.

```
=sumifs(Main!B:B="Completed",Main!H:H,"<30")
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response. I'm trying to reverse engineer it so I understand it, but I am not sure what and why it is referencing the I column. I this supposed to be a hidden column? ibb.co/w6vLPK7 is a screenshot of my excel sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using COUNTIFS:

For 30 days window in the future:

```
=COUNTIFS(Main!B:B,"Completed",Main!I:I,">="&TODAY(),Main!I:I,"<"&TODAY()+30)
```

For 30 days window in the Past:

```
=COUNTIFS(Main!B:B,"Completed",Main!I:I,"<"&TODAY()+1,Main!I:I,">="&TODAY()-30)
```

Comment: I'll add a good practice to this would be to avoid using the entire column to count or sum for performance reasons. (For OP. Not you, Scott your answer is very well done). Is there a reason you used "<" & +1 instead of "<="?

Comment: @MarkS. `TODAY()` returns just the date and if there is a time element to the date column anything with today's date and a time after `00:00` would not meet `"<=` so I add a day and do less than to get all times in today as well.

Comment: That's a good adjustment, especially considering the OP hadn't mentioned it. No harm if the data included, no harm if it didn't. Well done. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response.  I'm trying to reverse engineer it so I understand it, but I am not sure what and why it is referencing the I column.  I this supposed to be a hidden column?  https://ibb.co/w6vLPK7 is a screenshot of my excel sheet

Comment: Change the I to what ever column has your dates.

Comment: I assumed that was the way it was supposed to be and actually tested with that.  but getting a 0 as result - Currently formula would be =COUNTIFS(B:B,"Completed",H:H,">="&TODAY(),H:H,"<"&TODAY()+30)  .  Realizing the column thing is a bad idea but just trying to get it to function then a I can adjust and say which cells.  I also tried to just state the cells instead of using column but got same results

Comment: Are your dates actual dates and not text that look like dates?  Without seeing a mock up of the data we are totally guessing.

Comment: Yes they are https://ibb.co/w6vLPK7 I know people arent keen to click on links but this is just to a img dump site

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS(Main!B:B,"Completed",Main!H:H,"<="&TODAY(),Main!H:H,"<"&TODAY()+30)
```